# While running TensorFlow's classify_image, getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gfile'

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting this error while running the sample file given with TensorFlow, in the imagenet model,

```
File "classify_image.py", line 154, in run_inference_on_image
if not tf.gfile.Exists(image):
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gfile'

I have tried installing using both, from pip as well as source, on virtualserver as well, still I get this error.

Comment: This gfile stuff was added 6 days ago in this commit -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/27bbe92711a93613eca843772b6e7eb32ff96c35   , might be worth filing an issue on github. As a workaround, you can undo the gfile stuff locally back into os.path, it's only a few lines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to go about solving this problem:

### Option 1

This is an expansion on Yaroslav's comment above, and is easier than option 2.

Modify `classify_image.py` as follows:

Replace all instances of `tf.gfile.Exists` to `os.path.exists`, and
replace all instances of `tf.gfile.GFile` and `tf.gfile.FastGFile` to `open`

Then run the modified `classify_image.py`, and it should work.

### Option 2

Update tensorflow to the latest version that includes `gfile` as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html)

However, after you do that, you might encounter the following error when you try to run `classify_image.py`:

```
$ python classify_image.py
>> Downloading inception-2015-12-05.tgz 100.0%
Succesfully downloaded inception-2015-12-05.tgz 88931400 bytes.
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc:207] A protocol message was rejected because it was too big (more than 67108864 bytes).  To increase the limit (or to disable these warnings), see CodedInputStream::SetTotalBytesLimit() in google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classify_image.py", line 213, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/mlnd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "classify_image.py", line 209, in main
    run_inference_on_image(image)
  File "classify_image.py", line 159, in run_inference_on_image
    create_graph()
  File "classify_image.py", line 141, in create_graph
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

To fix this, you can change a line in the source code as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/582) and then recompile tensorflow on your machine.

Option 2 might be a bit of work, especially if you're on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps helped me resolve the issue

1. update tensorflow  as described here https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html

2.For me this resulted in protobuf error. To resolve I ran

> > $sudo pip uninstall protobuf
> >
> > $sudo pip install --upgrade
> >     https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-any.whl